Visiting the UK from Kazakhstan: medical requirements?
My girlfriend, who lives in Kazakhstan, will be coming to the UK mid-January 2025, and she has been told by her travel agent that she needs to have a medical exam before she flies. She is in perfect health, so my question is: is it true that she needs a medical before she can fly to the UK on a visitors visa for a stay of 28 days, or not?

Does she already have a visitor's visa? A medical might be required for an extended visit to show absence of tuberculosis. What does the UK visa advice say? And... have you ever met? If not, is she asking for money? It might not be a scam, but scammers try to milk the target at every step, once they have them "on the hook".

If she’s supposed to be coming on a standard visitor visa (max allowed stay 6 months) for 28 days, then no, a medical is not a requirement. Nor is health insurance obligatory, or demonstrating a specific amount of money in her bank account. She also doesn’t need to pay a travel /visa agent to help with the online application (you can do that yourself  from the UK). Basically, if this is an online friendship only, she doesn’t need any money up front for anything in order to apply. See Visit guide

She will be applying for a short term visitors visa only and that is when she was told she would need a medical.

Does she need money to pay for the medical? Is she your fiancée or proposed civil partner?

What is the scope of the medical? There are different medicals for different purposes.

Go to the government website and apply for a visa as if you were her. That will tell you all the requirements. You should be able to actually apply for the visa on her behalf. Then get her to tell her travel agent that she will get the visa herself. If the agent says that's not allowed then ditch the agent.

@user188170 She doesn’t need a medical to apply for a visa to visit you as a tourist in the UK. Ask her to ask the visa agent where the requirement is stated in the UK visa rules. The agent might be scamming her or, if she’s asking you for money up front and you’ve never met her in person, you are being scammed.

Note that the following relates to visits of 6 months or more.  You stated a 28 day visa, so this advice is technically irrelevant.  But I'm leaving it up for information only.

Based on the UK government website here it is possible that your GF could need to take a TB test.  That website states:

You’ll need to have a tuberculosis (TB) test if all of the following
are true:

you’re coming to the UK for 6 months or more

you’ve lived in any of these listed countries for 6 months or more

you were living there (or another listed country) within the last 6    months



The listed countries are shown here, and yes Kazakhstan is on that list.
Arghh .. I can't read, and jumped the gun.  It clearly says All, but I read that as any.

However, the same site also says:

If you’re coming to the UK for less than 6 months, you’ll still need a
TB test if you’re applying for a Returning Resident visa, or a family
visa as a fiancé, fiancée or proposed civil partner.


Note that on this site we are skeptical about relationships with people you have not previously met in person, and asking about their travel plans.  There are a lot of romance scams going on, and we just like to make sure this isn't one of them.  Not that you've given enough information about that.

all of the following? 28 days is less than 6 months.

@WeatherVane yeah, I can't read, but I'm leaving it up as a contra-indication

@WeatherVane See update: the TB test also applies to some short term visas as well.  But I'm not sure what sort of visa the OP is actually talking about.

Thanks, but those conditions could ring the alarm bell mentioned in my first comment at the top.

It could be an overzealous travel agent that can't properly read English (like me), or it could be a scammer relying on someone not knowing the actual requirements, or it could be the type of visa involved.

...or a scammer who knows the medical requirement for a 'love interest'.
